# Error al agregar un nuevo elemento en un AarrayObject en PHP utilizando la función append y arreglos multidimensionales

Tags: php, array, poo, php7

Estoy probando el `ArrayObject` de `PHP` creando un arreglo multidimensional

```
$array = new ArrayObject(array("Indice" => "Ejemplo", "Array" => array("Array1" => array("AD1" => "Dato1", "AD2" => "Dato2"),"Array2" => array("AD2_1" => 1, "AD2_2" => 2))));
```

Y lo que deseo es que en el **`Array2`** agregar nuevos datos

```
$array["Array"]["Array2"]->append(array("Prueba" => "Ejemplo"));
```

lo que me arroja el siguiente error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function append() on array

otra observación en caso de funcionar.

Entiendo que

`append(array("Prueba" => "Ejemplo"))`
Me crea un nuevo arreglo, pero si sólo quiero agregar un valor mas, es decir:
`append("Prueba" => "Ejemplo")`

Es la primera vez que lo utilizo y me interesaría conocer ambos conceptos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error te lo está diciendo claro: **`Call to a member function append() on array`**.

Si haces un `var_dump($array);` verás que en `$array["Array"]["Array2"]` no hay un `ArrayObject`, sino un array como cualquier otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Por tanto, si quieres agregar un nuevo valor en ese simple y humilde array, tienes que hacerlo como se hace para agregar valores en los arrays, simplemente esto:

```
$array["Array"]["Array2"][]=(array("Prueba" => "Ejemplo"));
```

O, imaginemos que quieres ponerlo en el índice `AD3_3`, del simple y humilde array, tendrías que hacer esto:

```
$array["Array"]["Array2"]["AD3_3"]=(array("Prueba" => "Ejemplo"));
```

Es sencillamente eso: `$array["Array"]["Array2"]` es un array y debes tratarlo como tal.

---

Si consideramos la siguiente estructura el código original funcionaría:

```
$array = 
    new ArrayObject(
        array(
            "Indice" => "Ejemplo", 
            "Array" => array(
                "Array1" => 
                    array(
                            "AD1" => "Dato1", "AD2" => "Dato2"
                          ),
                "Array2" => 
                    new ArrayObject(
                        array(
                                "AD2_1" => 1, "AD2_2" => 2
                             )
                    )
                )
        )
    );
```

Hagamos una prueba:

```
$array["Array"]["Array2"]->append(array("Prueba" => "Ejemplo"));
var_dump($array);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Indice"]=>
    string(7) "Ejemplo"
    ["Array"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Array1"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["AD1"]=>
        string(5) "Dato1"
        ["AD2"]=>
        string(5) "Dato2"
      }
      ["Array2"]=>
      object(ArrayObject)#2 (1) {
        ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["AD2_1"]=>
          int(1)
          ["AD2_2"]=>
          int(2)
          [0]=>
          array(1) {
            ["Prueba"]=>
            string(7) "Ejemplo"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Supongo que no será difícil entender por qué ahora sí funciona ...

Comment: Por lo que entiendo es que el objeto que envuelve a los demás arreglos (`New ArrayObject() `) es quien sería eso `ArrayObject` y al cual la función `append() ` si inserta valores nuevos, ergo, los arreglos internos, son simples arreglos y los que tienen que ser tratados como tal. Así es como lo entiendo.

Comment: @FernyCortez entiendes bien. Si quisieras agregar algo a `$array` directamente (que sí es un ArrayObject) entonces sí deberías usar `append`.

Comment: Una pregunta derivado de lo mismo, se puede crear un `ArrayObject` dentro del mismo? , por ejemplo `. append(new ArrayObject("AO" =>"Nuevo Dato")) `

Comment: @FernyCortez revisa lo que he puesto al final de la respuesta.

Comment: Y también se pueden anidar ArrayObjects, puedes hacer esta prueba en el segundo código: `$array["Array"]["Array2"]->append(new ArrayObject(array("AO" =>"Nuevo Dato")));`, @FernyCortez.